# Convert CRT to PFX file (without key) to be installed on IIS

Tags: ssl, iis, certificate, ssl-certificate, pfx

I have an SSL certificate that is from one server and needs to be installed on a Windows server, as well. The SSL Certificate export might not be from Windows. I think it's probably Apache (I don't have direct control). The file is in .crt format. As I understand it, I need to first convert to a .pfx file and then I can import the .pfx file into IIS.

I don't have a key file. Just the .crt file. Do I need a key file from the original server or a key file from where the certificate will be installed?

I have done this process in the past using command-line (maybe openssl). If I recall correctly, for that instance, I also didn't have a key file. I think I may have just made up a key file and entered my own password and was able to convert .crt to .pfx with no issues.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `I don't have a key file` -- then your mission is impossible. PFX and IIS require private key. You have to get a key from original server.

Comment: Hmm. I think I recall that I used a tool in the past (again, maybe openssl) to generate a key for the certificate. I was reading up on DigiCert and how it can re-key the certificate, if it cannot find a key on the server you're installing the certificate on.

Comment: No tool can generate private key for existing certificate/public key. You have to get private key from original server.

Comment: Hmm. This article seems to suggest it's doable to re-key the certificate, if you cannot locate it: https://www.digicert.com/blog/where-is-your-private-key. `If you are using Windows, then your private key is stored in a hidden folder. The DigiCert Utility is a free tool you can use on Windows machines to locate a private key for a certificate by importing a certificate file into the Utility. If no valid private key is found, you can also use the DigiCert Utility to re-key your certificate.`

Comment: The article talks about \*new* CSR generation and \*new* certificate issuance. Old and new certificates will have different key pairs. It doesn't say that you can generate private key for existing cert. You have to get private key from original server.